# Using SBT with scala using offline dependencies

Tags: scala, sbt, offline

I'm currently evaluation scala and SBT for a new project. This will be a commercial project that I will have to support even in a few years from now. So I need to make sure I can build old versions from version control again any time in future on any PC. I want to manage external libraries and even the scala compiler under version control.

Just putting all jars into .lib may produce issues when updating to newer scala (runtime) versions, so I'd like to use SBT to build those external libraries against current scala version automatically but completely offline. Mainly because some libraries might not be available online anymore in a specific version in future.

Any hints on how to achieve my goal?

Comment: Is the unavailability of dependencies really that big of a concern? The Maven.org repository still hosts JARs that go back to 2005.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own personalized maven or ivy repo for your unmanaged dependencies and keep all versions available there. And all managed dependencies in public repositories are hosted for a long time.